# Using AMPScript to retrieve multiple order lines from Sales cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to create an email that provides the customers an order confirmation email with multiple line items associated with price and qty. I will attach the sample email template how it should look like. I have created a journey builder - Salesforce entry data event with considering two custom objects, which automatically creates a data extension. I am using that data extension to create an email to retrieve the data.

Could you please help me in achieving this with sample AMPscript.

Please find the attached documents of the data we need.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: What error you getting

Comment: DEColumn1 is not displaying ?

Comment: I am receiving the same email with no data. The email contains with same content with AMPScript.

Comment: close your code begin with %%[         end with ]%% this before DEColumn1  then try

Comment: One more question, there is no data in the data extension for Site_Order_Detail__r:Extended_Price__C. How should I solve that issue

Comment: without value for this column Site_Order_Detail__r:Extended_Price__C   then what you want display in  DEColumn1

Comment: you need to display none ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reviewing the [**LookupOrderedRows()**](https://ampscript.guide/book/LookupOrderedRows/) example on this page and modifying it for your DE and fields.

You'll need to determine what field from your journey's entry data extension is the connection to the order confirmation data.  That key value is what you need to use for `@lookupValue`.

The first parameter of the LookupOrderedRows function should be the data extension that contains the order data.

Inside the for-loop, you can update the variables to match the column names in your order data extension.

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue = AttributeValue("Region") /* value from attribute or DE column in send context */
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all, max 2000 */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("LoyaltyMembers", @numRowsToReturn, "rank desc, firstName asc", "region", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

output(concat("region: ", @lookupValue))

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @firstName, @emailAddress, @rank
    set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
    set @rank = field(@row,"rank")
    set @firstName = field(@row,"firstName")
    set @emailAddress = field(@row,"emailAddress")

    ]%%

    <br>Row %%=v(@i)=%%, rank: %%=v(@rank)=%%, firstName: %%=v(@firstName)=%%, emailAddress: %%=v(@emailAddress)=%%

    %%[

  next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Answer (score -2):

use like that

```
           %%[ 
           your amp script code here
          ]%%
        DEColumn1 is %%=v(@DEColumn1)=%%
```